# Why File.OpenRead() appends relative path to the executable file?

Tags: c#, .net

Why while using the following code

```
string filePath = @"‪C:\test\upload.pdf"
FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filePath);
```

raises the following exception?

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect : 
'C:\ConsoleApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\‪‪C:\test\upload.pdf'
```

From where the `C:\ConsoleApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\‪‪` directory comes from?

**Update:**
The `File.OpenRead()` in my case, exists within in an dll & the `filePath` (‪`C:\test\upload.pdf`) is sent via the application that is using the dll.

Comment: `File.OpenRead` doesn't do any such thing. Post code that *actually* reproduces the problem and post the full exception text, including the call stack. You can get that easilyt with `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: there's no need to. `File.OpenRead` is such a fundamental call that *every* .NET Core developer would have noticed the problem. Clearly, the string isn't a valid path. The most likely cause would be invalid or invisible characters, or characters that look like `:` or `\ `

Comment: Put your cursor at the " of "‪C:\. Press right a few times. What (odd) thing do you notice? _If you don't notice it, try again._ Another way to detect these kinds of issues is to check the length of the string - any odd behaviour with strings, check their length before investigating further. Invisible characters are, by their nature, hard to see - but they will impact the length.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The string starts with an invisible character, so it's not a valid path. This

```
(int)@"‪C:\test\upload.pdf"[0]
```

Returns

```
8234
```

Or hex `202A`. That's the [LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm) punctuation character

**UPDATE**

Raymond Chen posted an article [Why is there an invisible U+202A at the start of my file name?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150506-00/?p=44924).

> We saw [some time ago](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/12/19/10483396.aspx) that you can, as a last resort, insert the character U+202B (RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING) to force text to be interpreted as right-to-left. The converse character is U+202A (LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING), which forces text to be interpreted as left-to-right.
>
> The Security dialog box inserts that control character in the file name field in order to ensure that [the path components are interpreted in the expected manner](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/10/26/10362864.aspx). Unfortunately, it also means that if you try to copy the text out of the dialog box, the Unicode formatting control character comes along for a ride. Since the character is normally invisible, it can create all sorts of silent confusion.
>
> (We’re lucky that the confusion was quickly detected by Notepad and the command prompt. But imagine if you had pasted the path into the source code to a C program!)

In the 4 years since that article Notepad got UTF8 support so the character *isn't* replaced by a question mark. Pasting into the current Windows Console with its incomplete UTF8 support still replaces the character.

Comment: @Bogdan Doicin: the very 1st character (LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING, with `0x202A` code) which is *invisible* is wrong. Retype `"C:` fragment

Comment: @BogdanDoicin no, I'm saying that the *string* is wrong to begin with. Where did you get that string? Did it come from a Right-To-Left textbox? Did someone actually *add* the character there?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I would be searching for ages. That was it. You describe the whole thing above. I copied the path from the properties of the file in windows

Comment: @OrElse you'll find a lot of SO questions where the problem was caused by invisible characters or strange combinations, like `...` as a single character, or worse, `, ` ie comma-space as a single Unicode character in a CSV file

Answer (score -3):

The File.OpenRead() in my case, exists within in an dll .

Set the CopyLocal= true in properties of dll in which File.OpenRead exists.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with existence. `File.OpenRead` treats the string as if it wasn't a path. Every other function would do the same because it's *not* a valid path - it starts with an invisible character